# Putting locator from GPS coordinates in 3D projected map

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, gps

I'm new to maps and not so good in math and geometrics.

I have a [2d google map](https://goo.gl/maps/NKyDjsyyicuhFiut7).

I have to put a 2d projection of this map (not exactly this one but a handpainted one, so I will not violate any copyright) in an app (that must work offline, so I cannot use external API but only math resources on the smartphone):

[image]

I need to put a locator (on this projection) in real time, calculating it from GPS position of the user.

For example, if the user is [here](https://goo.gl/maps/cMoEeSH1xgZCR6516) (45.064768 N, 7.695454 E), I will put the locator here:

[image]

In other words, **I need to know how can I calculate X and Y distance from the upper left corner of the projection** (I know the GPS position of all four corners of the projection).

I also seem to understand that this math calculation has something to do with a rotated perspective grid:

[image]

I will manage this "GPS coords to XY" manipulation using javascript.

I don't need the final "copy and paste" solution but only an idea on how to proceed, explained in words as simple as possible.

---

After some brainstorming I understand that I could start from a trapezoidal shape laying on a 2d map (from top):

[image]

Then, if I will observe this shape from behind, this isosceles trapezoidal view will become a perspective view (what I want to show in my app) but with a rectangular shape, due the inclination (no more from the top but e.g. from 45° degrees):

[image]

Considering a given point on the "flat" map, I can get distance and angle from the four vertex of the isosceles trapezoid.

Then, I must "transpose" these distance and their angles on the resulting rectangle. I think it can be quite easy to do so, although I believe there'll some errors doing in this way (due to a lot of missing other parameters):

[image]

Comment: I believe you are looking for the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection. There are implementations of thia on OpenCV, or you could create a Postgis function to do it.

Comment: Actually, I think you need the axonometric projection, as it appears to be rotated as well as tilted. This kind of map, as you have shown, ia generally called 2.5D.

Comment: I feel that I must find something less tricky. The top view is a way ugly for my app, but this projection is too hard to handle.

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest thing would be to find out the coefficients of a matrix of projective transformation between one plane and another. Which I think would be possible by having 4 known coordinate points in both systems. When you put the coordinates, I deleted my comment requesting them because it (my comment) was no longer necessary, but now I don't know if you deleted the coordinates because they were not correct or because you thought they would no longer be necessary.

Comment: The transformation is clearly not-affine: parallel lines cease to be parallel when mapped. However, an affine transformation differs from a projective one in the coefficients of the last row of the transformation matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix). If we project the geographic coordinates of the corners to a plane (probably custom Transverse Mercator) we could try to find the matrix of a 2D to 2D projective transformation to the image plane.

Comment: I would consider it the least tricky solution, even if it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Yes, as Gabirel says, this really is not hard. OpenCV will find the projective transform.

Comment: I've found a lot of JS references about perspective transform (and not projective). But, looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716732/2d-perspective-transform-in-javascript, it seems to be the right one for me. Or not?

Comment: It was too tough for my math and geolocations knowings, so I ended using flat map viewed from the top. Maybe I will retry in the future. Thanks anyway.